# Way to store a single line of changing text on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3, heroku-postgres

I am running a python script on Heroku which runs every 10 minutes using the Heroku-Scheduler add-on.  The script needs to be able to access the last time it was run.  On my local machine I simply used a .txt file which I had update whenever the program was run with the "last run time".  The issue is that Heroku doesn't save any file changes when a program is run so the file doesn't update on Heroku.  I have looked into alternatives like Amazon S3 and Postgresql, but these seem like major overkill for storing one line of text.  Are there any simpler alternatives out there?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem, I ended up finding out about Heroku-redis which allows you to make key-value pairs and then access them. (Like a Cloud Based Python Dictionary)